# Error: Bad option "busy" while running a tcl standalone application

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have my code working fine, while running it through "tclsh filename.tcl".
Once i compiled it using sdx.kit and tcl basekit and re-executing the kit file, it throws me following error for tk busy command.

Not sure, what went wrong during kit compilation, but it happen always.
Here is snippet of my code.

```
proc create_mem_template {} {
tk busy hold .top
update
tk busy configure .top -cursor "watch"
........
........
........
tk busy forget .top
```

[image]

Attaching the snapshot of my error.

Comment: What is your version? I believe tk busy was added in 8.6.

Answer (score 1):

The `busy` subcommand was added Tk 8.6 (as proposed in [TIP #321](http://www.tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/321.html)); if you're using an earlier version, you'll need to upgrade.

Comment: I am using TCL 8.6 version. Do i need to use another version for tclkit and sdx.kit.

Comment: But are you using **Tk 8.6**? I think it might be possible (though _really_ not recommended) to use Tk 8.5 with Tcl 8.6. If you've ended up in a situation where that's what's happening, that's a significant issue.

Comment: How can i check whether i am using Tk8.6 ? Okay, but i can't have 2 installations and also can't ask users to do that way... I think to have an alternative to this problem.